# Disabling column menu for specific column in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

Is it possible to disable column menu for specific column in Kendo UI Grid? And if it is, how it should be done?

Comment: Would you mind rephrasing your question, it's not clear! Which columns in KendoUI do you mean? Grid?

Comment: I edited the question. Yes, I ment the kendo grid.

Comment: Sorry for being picky :-) By column _menu_ do you mean the title? If so, then when you define `columns` define the `title` as a white space: `title:" "`

Comment: @OnaBai: Column menu is a feature of Kendo UI Grid.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Out of the box you can only exclude the column from being shown/hidden through the column menu (i.e. there wont be a checkbox defined for that column which you can check/uncheck). To do so you should use the **menu** option when defining your column.
e.g.

```
    jQuery("#Grid").kendoGrid({
    "columns": [{
        "title": "Person ID",
        "menu": false, //this way
        "field": "PersonID" 
    },
    {
        "field": "Name",
        "encoded": true
    },
    //...
```

If you want you completely hide the column menu for lets say the 3rd column you can use the following work-around:

```
$(function(){
     $('#GridName .k-header-column-menu').eq(2).hide()
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in kendo ui for Razor MVC?

Comment: You can apply the same approach when using the Wrappers for MVC however you still need to code that hide logic in JavaScript ;)

Comment: Hi Petur, also, i want to disable column menu from only a specific column.. is this also possible?

Comment: More than one year and this simple feature wasn't implemented.

Comment: can we hide some of the option from column menu for a particular column?

Comment: [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.menu)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in MVC when defining the columns. Sample code is as as below.

columns.Bound(person => person.FirstName).IncludeInMenu(false);

Comment: This only removes the column from the selection list within the column menu. You have to use a workaround like Petur's above to hide the column menu on a specific column.